# CABasicAnimation: From left to right

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

With the following piece of code, I am able to animate a CALayer from left to right

```
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 100, height: 70)
imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "first_image")?.cgImage

let animation = CABasicAnimation()
animation.keyPath = "position.x"
animation.fromValue = 100
animation.toValue = 300
animation.duration = 3
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
animation.repeatCount = 2
imageLayer.add(animation, forKey: "basic")

self.view.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
```

What I am trying to do is, in

> Cycle: 1 - "first_image" will move from left to right

and in

> Cycle: 2 - "second_image" (this is another image) will move from left
>   to right like previous cycle.

Here **Cycle: 1** + **Cycle: 2** is actually a single animation and I want this animation to happen for a number of times. How to achieve this?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you required left to right & vice versa animation, You can also use `UIView.anima..` for animation.

```
     let testViewTowardsLeft = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50))
    testViewTowardsLeft.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(testViewTowardsLeft)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {Bool in
        testViewTowardsLeft.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50)

    }, completion: nil)


    let testViewTowardsRight = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
    testViewTowardsRight.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(testViewTowardsRight)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {Bool in
        testViewTowardsRight.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)

    }, completion: nil)
```

[image]